# To convert Time from one timezone to another

Tags: python, time, pip

**Change time from UTC to the local timezone**

I have to write a script where the user will enter a tuple of hours and minutes *t(h,m)* in IST(*Indian*).
The entered time should be changed to the local time zone of the PC. Is there a library to do so in python. The time should also be returned in a tuple of hour and minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *time* module provides you with some constants including `time.timezone`, which gives the offset of the local (non-DST) timezone in seconds west of UTC. Subtracting India's timezone from user's timezone will give you the time difference in hours, which you can use to calculate your result.